# AngularJS no me reconoce el controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model-view-controller

Cuando abro la página no me tira un 'true' como debería, sino que me muestra  `{{ 2 > 1 }}`  como si no reconociera el controller.

¿Qué puedo hacer? ¿Tengo algún error?

Tengo que decir que aun estoy aprendiendo como funcionan las versiones recientes de angular.

```js
var app = angular.module('refinanciadorApp', []);
    
    app.controller('mainCtrl', function(){
     
    })
```

```html
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="refinanciadorApp">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Refinanciador</title>
      <base href="/">
    
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
       <!--bootstrap-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="mainCtrl as vm">
      
      <h1>The sky is {{ 2>1 }}ly blue</h1>
    
      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Boostratp's JS plugins) -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!--compiled  plugins -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <Script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js" charset="utf-8"></Script>
      <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

La parte JS tiene nada porque solamente necesito ese 'true'

Comment: Cual es la *versión reciente* de angular? Ese modulo esta presente en el html como ng-app?

Comment: Por lo que puedo ver, funciona correctamente. De todas formas puedes ver cualquier tipo de error que se genera con la consola de desarrollador en los navegadores (F12)

Comment: Según veo en tu app.js, esa versión es angularjs (v1), no es la versión más actual de angular :\
A no ser que te quieras referir a las versiones más nuevas dentro de angularjs.
Las versiones más actuales con Angular 2, 4 e incluso ya 5

Comment: @MatiasCazas puedes cambiar la linea del CDN de angular cdnjs.cloudflare.com... Por esta ajax.googleapis.com... y te funcionara correctamente.

Comment: en efecto, era el problema de la version. Muchisimas gracias!